# error instalación Homebrew (incorrecta PATH)

Tags: rutas, homebrew

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]instalando Homebrew me sale el siguiente mensaje:

Warning: /usr/local/bin is not in your PATH.

por favor me podríais explicar cómo hay que poner la correcta "PATH", tendría que buscar la ruta del archivo bin de homebrew?, sería correcto poner una ruta debajo de la otra?

Estoy en MacOS Catalina versión 10.15.7.

Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En caso de utilizar `bash` ejecuta en la consola:

vim .bash_profile

Después, agrega a la variable PATH lo siguiente:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Gracias, tendría que buscar la ruta del archivo bin de homebrew?, seria correcto poner una ruta debajo de la otra? (he adjuntado una imagen en el post inicial).